# Как получить данные из manytimany таблицы?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть два класса Child и Guardian. В классе Guardian есть поле:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "guardian_child", schema = "cheer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "guardianid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "childid"))
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

У меня создается таблица указанная в аннотации.

Но также мне надо написать функцию в контроллере, которая будет получаться данные из таблицы по guardianid:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getchildrenid/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Long> getChildrenId(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id) {
    // code here
}
```

Нужно ли мне для этого создать Сущность GurdianChild и репозиторий и сервис для этого? Или есть другие способы?

Comment: на таблицу связи вам отдельная сущность не нужна, ели вы про это

Comment: да, про это. но основной вопрос как мне обратиться к таблице внутри метода контроллера, чтобы получить все id Child'ов по id Gurdian'а

Comment: а зачем вам список всех id Child'ов ?

Comment: Предполагается, что Guardian может посмотреть всех детей, прикрепленных к нему, например. Т.е. с помощью этого метода получить нужные id Child'ов, а затем при желании вывести о них всю информацию находя их по id

Comment: запросы вы делаете через репозиторий, получаете там объекты, потом забираете то что из них нужно. Только вам надо не список id а список сущностей

Comment: Мне нужно сделать отдельный репозиторий, верно? Т.е. GuardianChildRepository? Если так, то что тогда я должен указать в `public interface GuardianChildRepository extends JpaRepository<???, Long>` на месте "???"

Comment: Список id нужен, так как у меня также есть таблица с координатами, где поиск ведется по id Child'а

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```
@Autowired
private GuardianService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getchildrenid/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Children> getChildren(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id) {
     Guardian guardian = service.getGuardian(id);
     return guardian.getChildrens();
}
```